# What's a smooth neighborhood? Why can it result from a transition map?

Tags: smooth-manifolds

What's a smooth neighborhood? Why can it result from a transition map?

Particularly I found this in a proof for the maximal atlas being smooth. Here one constructs a composition of two transition maps, but then it's said that the composition is "a smooth neighborhood of $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ (which was shown earlier)".

But I wonder, how does this definition make sense.

I've thought neighborhoods are sets, but smoothness is a property of functions.

So how can one have smooth neighborhoods?

Maybe it tries to say that the image is a neighborhood of $x$, but the structure in hand is also a smooth structure.

Comment: Which book are you following?

Comment: @MayureshL Lecture notes, but they could refer to Lee's Smooth Manifolds.

Comment: I think this is just a terminology to say whatever he has proved

Comment: @MayureshL He could have said, "the image of the smooth structure is a neighborhood of $x$"